# Accessing JavaFX UI elements from a different thread?

Tags: javafx

If my controller class is

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextArea msgArea;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    someThread.start();

    }

}
```

How can I change the value of my TextArea from the thread?

**EDIT: I used tasks to to solve this problem. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: In `JavaFX` it's best to work with a `Task` or `Service`. Depending on your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever needing to update a UI element from a thread, you must get the JavaFX UI thread to do so. Attempting to update an element from a different thread may lead to an exception, but could also lead to some unexpected behaviour.

Fortunately, JavaFX includes a useful way to do this. Simply add this in the code that runs on your separate thread:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    msgArea.setText("Your text");
});
```

It is better to use a task or service, because those provide in-built means of updating UI elements. For example, a task allows one to call `updateMessage("...")` or `updateProgress("...")`, which updates a bound element without you even needing to call the UI thread.

Comment: this answer is correct, just the wording _update an element from a different thread will throw an exception_ is a bit misleading: it may also silently do something (not necessarily what's expected), causing havoc that only shows later :)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks! I have edited the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I used tasks cause it seemed a lot easier.